# How to make Grid Layout through XML and Coding

Tags: android, grid-layout

Can anyone help me in making a Gridlayout of 3*3 for full screen using 9 images. My problem is that the images are not expanded, according to cell size.

Comment: Please post the code, that you have implemented. Also paste the screen shots of your emulator or device and point the Image View bounds that are not being displayed properly in your GridView.

Comment: GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent",android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"   android:layout_alignParentStart="false"                android:rowCount="3",android:columnCount="3"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:useDefaultMargins="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:background="#fffd0c">

Comment: the above code is Gridlayout

Comment: <ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageButton"
android:layout_row="0"
android:layout_column="0"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
android:layout_gravity="left|right|top|center|bottom"/>

Comment: i add 9 image with same ImageButton code..the problem is the output is not that what i want.

i use number of example from internet but not working...i just want my Image extract and stretch automatically on every screen of Android Phone

Comment: have anyone reply of my QUery ??

Comment: Now i pasted code dear......

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:numColumns="3"
```

in your layout xml for grid view